# Application Trigger from Background Task in uwp

Tags: uwp, background-task

I am trying to signal application trigger from a background task.
If the app is in foreground, the trigger works but after the app is suspended, the the background task is signals the application trigger. but the code in application trigger does not hit.

Background trigger is a 15 min time trigger.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Can you show how you signal your application trigger from background task?

Comment: await trigger.RequestAsync(); is used to signal the application trigger from background task. The trigger is static variable.

Comment: What's your purpose of triggering the ApplicationTrigger from the background task?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your issue. I wrote a demo project which fires a background task using 15 minute trigger, in the time trigger task Run methods, it's triggering the ApplicationTrigger using RequestAsync(), I can  see the ApplicationTrigger background gets triggered.

Comment: Hi Jackie, was the app in foreground or background. For me, application trigger fires when app is in foreground. But it does not fire when app is suspended. Could you tell me whether the app was in foreground or suspended. If the app was suspended, can you give me the code on github or something.

Comment: If you could update the question to show what your `App` object looks like, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is the designed behavior. The purpose of the ApplicationTrigger is to trigger background activity while the app is in the foreground. This activity can continue to run in the background after the foreground app goes away, but it can only be initiated from an app that has foreground rights.

Thanks,

Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform

Comment: hmmm, how come you did not mention this in my other post :).  ApplicationTrigger also sounds something interesting.